# how to investigate stuck process - perl script

Tags: linux, perl, process

I have some trouble with stuck process. I did some investigation, but I just could not find the root cause.

I use `ps aux | grep scriptname` to find the PID. And I did strace, it just stuck on read(5,

```
sudo strace -p 1939
Process 1939 attached - interrupt to quit
read(5,  <unfinished ...>
Process 1939 detached
```

I checked fd file in /proc:

```
sudo ls -l /proc/1939/fd | grep 5
Oct  9 21:20 5 -> pipe:[31041225]
```

I also used lsof, but I didn't get any clue from it:

```
/usr/sbin/lsof | grep 31041225
perl5.8.8  1939    5r     FIFO                0,6       0t0   31041225 pipe
perl5.8.8  2252    1w     FIFO                0,6       0t0   31041225 pipe
perl5.8.8  2252    2w     FIFO                0,6       0t0   31041225 pipe
bash       2290    2w     FIFO                0,6       0t0   31041225 pipe
bash       2298    2w     FIFO                0,6       0t0   31041225 pipe
original-  2302    2w     FIFO                0,6       0t0   31041225 pipe
```

But for my guess, it could be caused by the following code,

```
sub runScript {
   my $scriptName = $_[0];
   open(DATA, join(" ", @_) . " 2>&1 |");
   while (<DATA>) { 
      print $_;
   }
   close DATA;
}
```

Need some thoughts on what would be the next step...

Comment: the args of runScript are script name and its arguments. e.g. runScript("ls", "-l");

Comment: I would add some print statements to the subroutine to verify the process is getting stuck in that particular part of the script. One at the top and the one on exit.  If you think the read is the issue, you could capture the output using back ticks ($a=\`@_ 2>&1\`) and then print $a.  That way it would not have to do a read.

Comment: Found the root cause. The process started by runScript was blocked. That's why strace tells it's reading from pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not having error checking on `open` is a serious problem.  Nevertheless, the code you have posted works with those arguments:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

runScript('ls','-l');

print "done!";

sub runScript {
   my $scriptName = $_[0];
   open(DATA, join(" ", @_) . " 2>&1 |") or die "Can't open filehandle: $!";
   while (<DATA>) { 
      print $_;
   }
   close DATA;
}
```

Calling this subroutine with different arguments *would* potentially cause your script to hang, though.  For example, run any command that waits for user input:

```
runScript('vim');
```

Now you will hang forever.